# How to simplify expressions by closing open inequalities?

Tags: simplifying-expressions, inequalities

Recently I have often acquired results which consist of combinations of 0, 1 and 2-dimensional (in)equalities. For instance, consider a very simple case with `ineq1` and `ineq2` below:

```
With[
 {ineq1 = x == 0 && y == 0 || x > 0 && -x <= y <= x,
  ineq2 = -x <= y <= x},
 Resolve[ForAll[{x, y}, ineq1 \[Equivalent] ineq2], Reals]]
```

> `True`

Mathematica thinks they're equivalent over $\mathbb{R}^2$. How can I simplify an inequality `ineq1` to form like `ineq2`? I have tried at least `FullSimplify`, `Reduce` and `Refine`, but none of them seem to grok my goal.

**EDIT:** Note that above example is really roughly the simplest one that can be imagined. On my ongoing experiments, especially maintaining (and creating) chained inequalities like `a <= x < b` as a part of the expression seems to be curiously complicated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's some work-in-progress code I have been playing with.

First we define a helper function which attempts to combine `And`ed comparisons (which result when using functions such as `LogicalExpand`) into `Inequality`, `Equal` and `Unequal` chains. It does this by making graphs of expressions, and finding paths connected components and cliques on them. It doesn't try to move components of comparison between sides of the comparison operator - there's clearly room for improvement in that regard.

```
ClearAll[collectInequalityChains];

collectInequalityChains[eq_] :=
 Module[{
   normeq,
   eqExtract, eqExtractStep,
   ineqExtract, ineqExtractStep,
   uneqExtract, uneqExtractStep},

  normeq = BooleanMinimize@LogicalExpand@eq //. {
     a_ > b_ :> b < a,
     a_ >= b_ :> b <= a};

  ineqExtractStep[{graph_Graph, ineqs_List}] :=
   Module[{largestpath, pathedges},
    largestpath = 
     First@TakeLargestBy[
       Flatten[FindPath[graph, Sequence @@ #, Infinity, All] & /@ 
         Flatten[{#, Reverse@#} & /@ Subsets[VertexList@graph, {2}], 
          1], 1], Length, 1];
    pathedges = DirectedEdge @@@ Partition[largestpath, 2, 1];
    {Subgraph[graph,
      DeleteCases[EdgeList@graph, Alternatives @@ pathedges], 
      EdgeLabels -> PropertyValue[graph, EdgeLabels]],
     Append[ineqs, 
      Inequality @@ 
       Riffle[largestpath, 
        PropertyValue[{graph, #}, EdgeLabels] & /@ pathedges]]}];
  ineqExtract[graph_Graph] := 
   And @@ Last@
     NestWhile[ineqExtractStep, {graph, {}}, 
      Not@*EmptyGraphQ@*First];

  eqExtractStep[{graph_Graph, eqs_List}] :=
   Module[{largestconnected},
    largestconnected = 
     First@TakeLargestBy[ConnectedComponents@graph, Length, 1];
    {GraphDifference[graph,
      Subgraph[graph, largestconnected]],
     Append[eqs, largestconnected]}];
  eqExtract[graph_Graph, op_Symbol] := 
   And @@ (op @@@ 
      NestWhile[eqExtractStep, {graph, {}}, 
        Not@*EmptyGraphQ@*First][[2]]);

  uneqExtractStep[{graph_Graph, eqs_List}] :=
   Module[{largestconnected},
    largestconnected = 
     First@TakeLargestBy[FindClique@graph, Length, 1];
    {GraphDifference[graph,
      Subgraph[graph, largestconnected]],
     Append[eqs, largestconnected]}];
  uneqExtract[graph_Graph, op_Symbol] := 
   And @@ (op @@@ 
      NestWhile[uneqExtractStep, {graph, {}}, 
        Not@*EmptyGraphQ@*First][[2]]);

  MapAt[eqExtract[Graph[UndirectedEdge @@@ Cases[#, _Equal, {0, 1}]], 
      Equal] &&
     uneqExtract[Graph[UndirectedEdge @@@ Cases[#, _Unequal, {0, 1}]],
       Unequal] &&
     ineqExtract[
      Graph[Property[DirectedEdge @@ #, EdgeLabels -> Head@#] & /@ 
        Cases[#, _Less | _LessEqual, {0, 1}]]] &, normeq, 
   Most /@ Position[normeq, And]]]
```

A simple example:

```
collectInequalityChains[
 a < b && c >= b && a == d && d == e || b > a || x != y && y != z]
```

> (d == a == e && a < b <= c) || (y != x && y != z) || a < b

Then we use this function as prettifier in a function which attempts to simplify inequalities by searching exhaustively for equivalence of original inequality and transformed variants of it. These variants either leave an comparison unchanged, replace it with `True` or `False`, or expand open inequality to closed one. The variant with smallest `LeafCount` after `collectInequalityChains` is given out as the solution.

```
ClearAll[simplifyComparisons];

simplifyComparisons[ineqtmp_, vars_] :=
 Module[{ineq, eqpos, ineqpos, eqtrans, ineqtrans},
  ineq = BooleanMinimize@LogicalExpand@ineqtmp;

  eqpos = Position[ineq, _Equal | _Unequal];
  ineqpos = 
   Position[ineq, _Less | _LessEqual | _Greater | _GreaterEqual];

  eqtrans = 
   Thread[eqpos -> MapThread[#1[Extract[ineq, #2]] &, {#, eqpos}]] & /@
     Tuples[{Identity, True &, False &}, Length@eqpos];

  ineqtrans = 
   Thread[ineqpos -> 
       MapThread[#1[Extract[ineq, #2]] &, {#, ineqpos}]] & /@ 
    Tuples[{Identity, # /. {Less -> LessEqual, 
         Greater -> GreaterEqual} &, True &, False &}, Length@ineqpos];

  First@TakeSmallestBy[
    collectInequalityChains@ReplacePart[ineq, #] & /@ 
     Select[Flatten[Table[Join[a, b], {a, eqtrans}, {b, ineqtrans}], 
       1],
      Resolve[
        ForAll[vars, 
         Evaluate[ineq \[Equivalent] ReplacePart[ineq, #]]], 
        Reals] &], LeafCount, 1]]
```

Now we can simplify our original toy problem:

```
simplifyComparisons[
 x == 0 && y == 0 || x > 0 && -x <= y <= x, {x, y}]
```

> -x <= y <= x